# Outlook 2013 sp1 Add In body.getAsync not working for appointments

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

**Outlook 2013 SP1**'s Add-In `body.getAsync` not working for appointments.

I have tried:

```
Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (result) {}
```

and

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (result) {}
```

Any ideas?  It works in all other versions supporting Add-Ins

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function for get the body in appointment

```
    function getBody() {
    var _item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    var body = _item.body;

    // Get the body asynchronous as text
    body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
        else {
            // Show data
            showDataDialog('Body', asyncResult.value.trim());
        }
    });
}
```

Note-  Getting the item body is an asynchronous function that requires a minimum mailbox requirement set version of 1.3. There are different ways of ensuring that your user has at least version 1.3, a good way is to set it in the manifest.

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'm not sure why it would work in all other versions except Outlook 2013 SP1 though.

Comment: @PatrickO'Connor - Is this code not work on Outlook 2013? or Are you  get any other solution?